# Share installed flatpack soft to all OS users

Tags: software-installation, flatpak

When I install from flathub.org a couple of software like LibreOffice, GIMP, Krita, etc.. I switch account to second non-admin user and cant found it on this another user OS account.
How to install flatpak software for all elementary OS users?